# Javascript TypeError when using Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, icingaweb2

I'm using the icingaweb2 nagvis module, which uses Leaflet to show a world map. Most things work, but when I click on the map, the following error is shown:

```
Javascript error occured: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined h t t p : / / icingaweb2.server/nagvis/frontend/nagvis-js/js/ExtLeaflet.js?v=1.9b12 (5)
```

I'm using version `Leaflet 1.0.3+ed36a04` of Leaflet.

Inspecting the error in Chrome:

```
VM184 ExtLeaflet.js?v=1.9b12:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

    at e.fire (VM184 ExtLeaflet.js?v=1.9b12:5)
    at e._fireDOMEvent (VM184 ExtLeaflet.js?v=1.9b12:6)
    at e._handleDOMEvent (VM184 ExtLeaflet.js?v=1.9b12:6)
    at HTMLDivElement.h (VM184 ExtLeaflet.js?v=1.9b12:6)
```

Can someone please help me fix the error?

Comment: Please use `leaflet-src.js` instead of `leaflet.js` to get more informative error stacks.

Comment: thank you

`if (this._events) {
   var listeners = this._events[type];

   if (listeners) {


    this._firingCount = (this._firingCount + 1) || 1;
    for (var i = 0, len = listeners.length; i < len; i++) {
     var l = listeners[i];


     l.fn.call(l.ctx || this, event); //this is problem line


    }

    this._firingCount--;
   }
  }`